# CKEditor - Tabs

Tags: css

I want to use really Tabs in `CKEditor`. This is possible with Formatted text.

For example:

```
It&#9;is&#9;really&#9;Tab
```

But the Steps of this Tabs only 4 spaces:

```
It  is  really  Tab
123456781234567812345678
```

And I want, that the Steps were always 8 Spaces, like this:

```
It      is      really  Tab
12345678123456781234567812345678
```

Changing `contents.css` helps with IE, but not with Chrome.

```css
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS 2.1 */
  word-wrap: break-word; /* IE7 */
  -moz-tab-size: 8;
  tab-size: 8;
}
```

EDIT:
My Problem in font-family. I forgot to write that.

```css
<pre><span style="font-family:Arial">
It&#9;is&#9;really&#9;Tab&#10;12345678123456781234567812345678</span></pre>
```

If I use any font-family, except Mono-fonts, then it's not work.
How can I repair this.

Any ideas?

Comment: look: https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_tabindex

Comment: @SyedAmirHussain That's completely another property.

Comment: Are you sure it is doesn't work in Chrome? Looks like it does: https://jsfiddle.net/9pgud011/

Comment: Yes, it works. My Problem in font-family. I forgot to write that.
<pre>
<span style="font-family:Arial">
It&#9;is&#9;really&#9;Tab&#10;12345678123456781234567812345678</span></pre>
If I use any font-family, then it's not work.
How can I repair this.

Answer (score 0):

[It shall work](http://caniuse.com/#search=tab-size). Seems like CKEditor overrides your rule by the one with higher specificity.

Default value of tab-size is 8 so it is definitely overridden somewhere. Use dev tools to find where.

Comment: Yes, it works. My Problem in font-family. I forgot to write that.
<pre>
<span style="font-family:Arial">
It&#9;is&#9;really&#9;Tab&#10;12345678123456781234567812345678</span></pre>
If I use any font-family, then it's not work.
How can I repair this.

Comment: To achieve adequate visual effect of tabs you shall chose monospace font.